# How to repostion/reset the selector closer to the object with mirror modifier still active?

Tags: modifiers, mirror

the question is on the Image.

[image]

if I reset orgion to 3d cusor is messes up the clipping and adjusting it does not help fix it.

[image]
Thank You...

Answer (score 1):

I Just figured it out:

[image]

1. Place 3d cursor where you want it.
2. Unselect *Clipping* on the *Mirror Modifier*.
3. In tools, *Set origin* select *Origin to 3D cursor*.
4. On the *Mirror Modifier*, re-select *Clipping*.
5. Adjust the *Merge limit* to place the two sides back together.

That looks like it worked.

Comment: writting or using actual number are a matter of option... terminology is a matter of getting to know what everyting is called.... lalalalala lame O mod ... is my option ...